# Python interface wifi.Cell.all(Interface) giving system error

Tags: python, interface, wifi

I am trying to connect to the wireless network using [wifi](https://wifi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). As per the documents I have written the code, but it gives system error that file not found. As I can see the argument description of the Cell.all() is interface but we are providing literal as argument. What might be the problem?

```
import time 
import datetime
from wifi import Cell, Scheme

while True :
    print datetime.datetime.now()
    print Cell.all('wlan0')
    time.sleep(5)

>>>
2015-01-25 12:38:43.784000

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Development\Script\AutoLogon.py", line 9, in <module>
print Cell.all('wlan0')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wifi\scan.py", line 29, in all
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
  process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
  startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The python interface wifi was developed for Linux. I may be able to use the library using cygwin.